# Translation method does not work

Tags: magento-1.7, javascript, localisation

```
someVar = <?php echo $this->__("Yes") ?>
```

seems to not work. Even when I try `console.log(<?php echo $this->__("Yes") ?>)`. Isn't `$this->__()` supposed to return just string?

I have the translation in the `*.csv` file and I know it's the correct one, because I work with other translations from that file in the same template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @David Manners for the note, it was helpful. Nevertheless, what solved my problem was using this: `'<?php echo Mage::helper('module_name')->__("Yes") ?>'`.

Comment: was type $this not the same as the helper that is odd?

Comment: @DavidManners - I know it's odd, because, as I said in the question, I use `$this->__(...)` for another translation from the same `.csv` file, in the same template and it works flawlessly...

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that in JavaScript your script is still encapsulated in quotations. Try the following code taking note of the semicolon and quotations.

```
someVar = '<?php echo $this->__("Yes") ?>';
```